# Emacs lisp list processing with spaces in list items

Tags: recursion, emacs, elisp

I have an emacs lisp list that says:

```
(setq states '(
              Nebraska
              NE
              Nevada
              NV
              New Hampshire
              NH
              New Jersey)
)
```

I created a function that prints only the state names, not the abbreviations:

```
(defun names (los)
  "Get names from list of states"
  (when los
    (print (car los))
        (names (cdr(cdr los)))
    )
  )
```

I call the function like: `(names states)` and get

```
Nebraska
Nevada
New
NH
Jersey
```

How do I tell my lisp function (or setup my list) so that a the spaces in the words are not delimiters, only the newlines are delimiters?

Thanks

Comment: Not an answer because I don't know elisp well, but don't you need to put strings inside quotes? e.g. `"Nebraska" "NE" "Nevada" "NV"...` and so on

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Elisp treats whitespace as a delimiter.  To answer the immediate question, you can do as Patrick suggested in his comment and put the strings in quotes.

More broadly, you should consider using an association list or a property list, as they are designed for the task you have in mind.  Read up on `assoc` and `plist-get` for more information.  Examples:

The alist version would look like:

```
(setq states-alist '((NH "New Hampshire")
                     (NE "Nebraska")
                     (NV "Nevada")))
(cadr (assoc 'NH states-alist))
```

The plist version would look like:

```
(setq states-plist '(NH "New Hampshire"
                     NE "Nebraska"  
                     NV "Nevada"))
(plist-get states-plist 'NH)
```

Answer (score 3):

As Patrick Collins [noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24042621/emacs-lisp-list-processing-with-spaces-in-list-items#comment37066380_24042621), you should turn the list items into strings by putting them inside double quotes:

```
(setq states '(
              "Nebraska"
              "NE"
              "Nevada"
              "NV"
              "New Hampshire"
              "NH"
              "New Jersey")
)
```

---

If you really want to, you can keep them as symbols (as they are now) by escaping spaces with backslashes, e.g. `New\ Hampshire`.  Whether to use symbols or strings depends on what you want to use them for.